# How can I find the Boston Airport settlement?

Tags: fallout-4

I see that there is a settlement called Boston Airport, yet I can't seem to find it in order to unlock it. Am I missing something plain, or is it a part of a quest or something like that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The settlement area is pretty small, so it's easy to miss.

It is the small rectangular area depicted in the following picture, south-west of the parking garage and north-west of the airport itself:

[image: Airport settlement]

The workshop is located near the wall at the back, between the two doors. Follow the red carpet.

However it can only be unlocked as part of a quest:

> You need to side with the Brotherhood of Steel either during the quest `The Molecular Level` (so you can build the teleporter there) or wait for the quest `Liberty Reprimed` (You have some parts to build).

But you're not missing much, as the ground is 100% made of concrete; you can't plant any food, which have been removed from the build bar anyway. There are some sweet spots where you can place water though.

It is also impossible to build a recruitment beacon to gain settlers (You have to move them there manually), guard posts, any type of stores, salvage stations or artillery pieces. Those items are also missing in the build bar.

This settlement is really focused around the two quests mentioned previously instead of being a viable place to build a thriving settlement.

Comment: I didn't do either of the things you suggest for unlocking this area, and still got access to it. Don't remember what the trigger was though.

Comment: @Iszi have you finished the main quests of the game? I guess it will unlock after the story if you don't side with the faction controlling it before.

Comment: Nope. I'm past both of the points you've mentioned, but I didn't use the one faction in the first quest and I had the settlement unlocked (and cleared for scrap) well before the second. I'm pretty sure I recall having had it unlocked even before the first, but I don't remember the trigger. Maybe the warehouse investigation?

Comment: Nukapedia seems very unclear on the trigger. Claims it can be done before BoS shows up, or as part of a few different quests. The wiki on Fextralife concurs with one of those quests.

Comment: I think you get access to the Boston Airport as soon as you board the Prydwen.

Comment: @DCShannon What if you never visit the brotherhood? Would it unlock anyway after the story?

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault I don't know. Probably. I could check, as I believe I have a couple finished playthroughs where I never joined the Brotherhood. I'll get back to you if/when I remember.

Comment: For me, it was unlocked when I boarded the Prydwen

Answer (score 2):

It's part of the brotherhood quest line.  At some point they ask you to build some components for a project at the workbench that will be used for:

> Liberty prime

You can't build a radio tower there so you can't attract settlers.  There is a mod that can change that though.

Answer (score 1):

No food can be placed that I know of. However, I sent a settler there for a supply line and built a beacon to get settlers. Was not able to build much at all. It said the limit was reached.

I was able to unlock it through the Brotherhood quest line after being on the Prydwen or whatever their ship is called.